# Java issues reading txt file and displaying data

Tags: java, java-io

I am having issues reading data from a file in java. Not sure why the output is not changing. I added a few SOUT lines to try and find the issue but still not seeing it. Basically I have a txt file with random account number, last name, balances. The user is prompted for an account number and the account info is displayed. the user is then asked for another account number or 9999 to quit. The first requested account is displayed without issue but when the user enters another account number it just displays the original account.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadBankAccountsRandomly {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Path custRecords = Paths.get("D:\\School\\2nd Sem\\OOP\\Module 7\\RochesterBankCustomerRecords.txt");
        final String ACCOUNT_NUM = "0000";
        final String LAST_NAME_FORMAT = "        ";
        final int NAME_LENGTH = LAST_NAME_FORMAT.length();
        final String BALANCE_FORMAT = "00000.00";
        String delimiter = ",";
        String s = ACCOUNT_NUM + delimiter + LAST_NAME_FORMAT + delimiter + BALANCE_FORMAT + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        final int RECSIZE = s.length();
        FileChannel fcCR = null;
        String findAccount;
        int accountNum;

        byte data[] = s.getBytes();
        final String EMPTY_ACCT = "0000";
        final String QUIT = "9999";
        String[] array;

        try {
            fcCR = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(custRecords, READ);
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            System.out.println("\nEnter account to display >> ");
            findAccount = input.nextLine();

            while (!findAccount.equals(QUIT)) {
                accountNum = Integer.parseInt(findAccount);
                System.out.println(accountNum);
                fcCR.position((long) accountNum * RECSIZE);
                System.out.println(fcCR.position());
                fcCR.read(buffer);
                s = new String(data);
                array = s.split(delimiter);
                if (array[0].equals(EMPTY_ACCT)) {
                    System.out.println("The account #" + accountNum + " does not exist.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Account #: " + array[0] + " Last Name: " + array[1] + " Account Balance: $" + array[2]);
                }
                System.out.println("Enter the next account number or 9999 to quit >> ");
                findAccount = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(findAccount);
            }
            fcCR.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Message: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
Enter account to display >>
1001
1001
24024
Account #: 1001 Last Name: Smith    Account Balance: $34000.00

Enter the next account number or 9999 to quit >>
1203
1203
1203
28872
Account #: 1001 Last Name: Smith    Account Balance: $34000.00

Enter the next account number or 9999 to quit >>

Comment: Where do you modify `data`? I see `s = new String(data)` but I never see it modified in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Method `ReadableByteChannel.read` reads a number of bytes equal to the remaining bytes in the given buffer. Since your `buffer` starts out empty, the first `fcCR.read(buffer)` will read `data.length` bytes into your `buffer`. After that first read, the `buffer` is "full". To be able to read new data for subsequent account inquiries, you need to reset the `buffer` before the call to `fcCR.read(buffer)`:

```
buffer.position(0);
fcCR.read(buffer);
```

That said, there are two other issues with your code:

1. `ReadableByteChannel.read` is not guaranteed to read all the available bytes in one go. This is why the method returns the number of bytes it has read (or -1 if there are no more bytes to read). Thus, you should place `fcCR.read(buffer)` in a loop.
2. The line `accountNum = Integer.parseInt(findAccount)` is an off-by-one error - unless the number of your first account is `0000`.

Comment: The fcCR.read(buffer) is in a while loop. Also my buffer doesn't start empty it is instantiated using the data variable.

Comment: Got it working added ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data); before the try block and added buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data); in the while loop after fcCR.read(buffer);

Comment: @HavannaMaker " Also my buffer doesn't start empty it is instantiated using the data variable." Before the first call to `fcCR.read`, your `buffer` has a capacity of `data.length` and its position is `0`. This is what I meant with "empty". After the first call to `fcCR.read` the `buffer`'s position is at its capacity limit, it is "full".

Comment: @HavannaMaker Your while loop for repeatedly asking for user input is not what I meant with "you should place `fcCR.read(buffer)` in a loop." You are assuming that each record in your file is 24 bytes in size (24 is the initial length of the `data` array). This is fairly small and chances are `read` will read that many bytes every time it is called. But `read` is not guaranteed to do that.

Comment: @HavannaMaker E.g. it could happen that `read` only reads 12 bytes. In that case, the first half of your `data` array would contain information about the new record and the second half of the array would contain information about the previous record. This is why a single call to `read` is not sufficient. You need something like: `int amountRead = 0;
for (int bytesRead = fcCR.read(buffer); bytesRead > -1 && data.length > amountRead; bytesRead = fcCR.read(buffer)) {
  amountRead += bytesRead;
}`.

Comment: @HavannaMaker See the fourth paragraph in the documentation for [read](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer)).

Answer (score 0):

You could trying re-factoring your code to use the *[java.io framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/package-summary.html)*, instead of the *[java.nio framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/package-summary.html)*.

Here is the *[java.io Class Hierarchy (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/package-tree.html)*.
And, here is the *[java.nio Class Hierarchy (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/package-tree.html)*.

Here is the Java tutorial on processing *I/O data* using either of those frameworks.
*[Lesson: Basic I/O (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html)*

The *java.io* framework is good for basic file reading and writing.
Whereas, the *java.nio* framework can prove daunting on general purpose access.

Essentially, the *java.nio* framework encapsulates the *[InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html)* and *[OutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html)* classes of the original *java.io*, in order to provide a more robust application in scalable and multi-tiered designs.

If you don't anticipate a divergence in your current design and concept, this might be a more logical approach.

Here's a demonstration of your application, utilizing the *java.io* framework.

I started by creating a local file, *RochesterBankCustomerRecords.txt*, with the following contents.

```
1000,LastNameA,12345
1001,LastNameB,54321
1002,LastNameC,98765
```

The class contains a nested class, *Account*, which holds a single account number, last-name, and account balance.
We'll utilize this class to hold the data from each line within the *RochesterBankCustomerRecords.txt* file.

```java
static class Account {
    String number, lastName, balance;
}
```

The enclosing class contains two fields.
The first is a *[File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html)* object, to hold the location of the text file.
The second is a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)* object, of type *Account*, which will hold each *Account*, from the file.

```java
File file = new File("files/RochesterBankCustomerRecords.txt");
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
```

There is a *load* method, which will be called during the class's default constructor method, to populate the *accounts* list.
I'm utilizing the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* class here, which offers a useful *[readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())* method.
Additionally, I'm using a *-1* as the second argument of the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int))* call.  This will preserve trailing commas, in the event any of the data in the file is empty.

```java
void load() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        Account account;
        String[] strings;
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            strings = line.split(",", -1);
            account = new Account();
            account.number = strings[0];
            account.lastName = strings[1];
            account.balance = strings[2];
            accounts.add(account);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a *lookup* method, which will traverse the *accounts* list, and return the corresponding *Account* object.
A *null* is returned if it is not found.

```java
/** @return null if not found */
Account lookup(String string) {
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (account.number.equals(string))
            return account;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also, there is a *ui* method, in which we'll utilize the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class as an input-source; exiting if no account number is entered, or *9999*.

```java
void ui() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string;
    Account account;
    boolean quit = false;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter account to display >> ");
        string = scanner.nextLine();
        if (string.isEmpty() || string.equals("9999")) quit = true;
        else {
            if ((account = lookup(string)) == null) {
                System.out.println("The account #" + string + " does not exist.");
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print("Account #: " + account.number);
            System.out.print(" Last Name: " + account.lastName);
            System.out.print(" Account Balance: $" + account.balance);
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (!quit);
}
```

Finally, there is a *start* method to provide access to the *ui* method.

```java
void start() {
    ui();
}
```

Here is the complete code, with a *main* method.

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Example example = new Example();
        example.start();
    }

    File file = new File("files/RochesterBankCustomerRecords.txt");
    List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    Example() throws IOException {
        load();
    }

    void start() {
        ui();
    }

    void ui() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string;
        Account account;
        boolean quit = false;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter account to display >> ");
            string = scanner.nextLine();
            if (string.isEmpty() || string.equals("9999")) quit = true;
            else {
                if ((account = lookup(string)) == null) {
                    System.out.println("The account #" + string + " does not exist.");
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.print("Account #: " + account.number);
                System.out.print(" Last Name: " + account.lastName);
                System.out.print(" Account Balance: $" + account.balance);
                System.out.println();
            }
        } while (!quit);
    }

    /** @return null if not found */
    Account lookup(String string) {
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.number.equals(string))
                return account;
        }
        return null;
    }

    void load() throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            Account account;
            String[] strings;
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                strings = line.split(",", -1);
                account = new Account();
                account.number = strings[0];
                account.lastName = strings[1];
                account.balance = strings[2];
                accounts.add(account);
            }
        }
    }

    static class Account {
        String number, lastName, balance;
    }
}
```

Here is an example input and output.

```
Enter account to display >> 1000
Account #: 1000 Last Name: LastNameA Account Balance: $12345
Enter account to display >> 1001
Account #: 1001 Last Name: LastNameB Account Balance: $54321
Enter account to display >> 1002
Account #: 1002 Last Name: LastNameC Account Balance: $98765
Enter account to display >> 1234
The account #1234 does not exist.
Enter account to display >> 9999
```